# Git - did init bare in wrong directory

Tags: git, undo, git-bare

I ran the `git --bare init` in a wrong directory(in the server). I see the files branches, config, deps etc., in that directory.. How do I undo it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since you performed a '--bare' init, there is no .git directory - instead the normal contents of the .git directory are directly in the parent directory.  For example, the place where you did 'git init --bare' looks something like:

```
$ git --bare init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/ebg/test/foo/
$ ls
HEAD        config      hooks/      objects/
branches/   description info/       refs/
```

to undo this simply perform:

```
rm -rf HEAD config hooks objects branches description info refs
```

Of course, be careful if you already had files and directories there with those names.

Answer (score 6):

If you did it on directory which wasn't previously set up as git repository, you can just remove .git folder (assuming you're using linux):

```
rm -rf .git
```

Otherwise, if directory already contained repository (.git directory), than git init would have no effect (i.e. git log will show the same commits before and after git init).

Comment: UPDATE: GoZoner's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10135410/754042) is actually the correct one, my answer is only applicable if git init was run without --bare switch.